# Solve a system of equations using Runge Kutta of order 4 in python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, ode, runge-kutta

I want to solve the following system using the numerical method Runge Kutta of order 4:

y'=-x-y
x'=-x+sin(t)

with initial conditions x(0)=0.75 and y(0)=0

Using RungeKutta of order code 4 I tried this:

```
def GlucoseTT(x, t, params):

a = params["a"]
b= params["b"]
c= params["c"]

xdot= np.array([a*x[0]-b*x[1], -c*x[0]+np.sin(t)])

return xdot



def RK4(f, x0, t0, tf, dt):
   t=np.arange(t0,tf,dt)
   nt=t.size

nx=x0.size
x=np.zeros((nx,nt))

x[:,0]=x0

for k in range(nt-1):
    k1= dt*f(t[k], x[:,k])
    k2= dt*f(t[k]+dt/2, x[:,k]+k1/2)
    k3= dt*f(t[k]+dt/2, x[:,k]+k2/2)
    k4= dt*f(t[k]+dt, x[:,k]+k3)
    
    dx=(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
    
    x[:,k+1]=x[:,k]+dx
return x, t

#Define Problem

params = {"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}
f= lambda t, x : GlucoseTT(x, t, params)

x0= np.array([0.75,0])


#Solve ODE
t0=0
tf= 100
dt= 0.1

x,t =RK4(f, x0, t0, tf, dt)

plt.plot(t,x[0,:],"r")
```

I dont' know if this code works....

Comment: I am not familiar with the math, but a search in the scipy docs shows a `scipy.integrate.RK45` among other Range-Kutta functions with different orders (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#solving-initial-value-problems-for-ode-systems). Would one of those work?

Comment: Please be more specific than "I dont' know if this code works...." Did you try it out and encountered an error? Did the program run through but gave unexpected results? /// Please investigate code formatting with code fences and correct the indentation to that of your actual code, especially in the RK4 function.

Comment: After fixing the indentation, the remaining problem is a careless and wrong transcription of the equation system. There are sign and index errors. Correcting them gives the expected forced oscillation with an amplitude leveling out at 0.5. /// I voted to close as this is a typo-level problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but the solution of the equations, so that you can compare:

```
X = C e^-t + (sin(t) - cos(t)) / 2
Y = D e^-t - C t e^-t + cos(t) / 2
```

The initial conditions give the system

```
0.75 = C - 0.5
0    = D + 0.5
```